# Atomikos, Tomcat, transaction logs and not observing system properties

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, atomikos

We are seeing the same as described at [Strange Atomikos exception - Error in init(): Log already in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014964/strange-atomikos-exception-error-in-init-log-already-in-use) except we've followed the documentation and specified a logging directory and base name as -D parameters. In our case it's a war file deployed into a naive Tomcat7 container instance.

There is no evidence in the log that the system properties are being read.

This is with 3.9.3 of Atomikos.

```
tomcat7  11466  2.5  0.7 2311632 257256 ?      Sl   09:13   0:19 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomca 7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dserver.properties.file=/usr/share/tomcat7/server-internal.properties -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir=/var/log/tomcat7/ -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name=rest-tm -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

The stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]: Factory method 'atomikosTransactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
        at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:456)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:326)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:405)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:569)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.startupTransactionService(UserTransactionManager.java:89)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.checkSetup(UserTransactionManager.java:77)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.setTransactionTimeout(UserTransactionManager.java:237)
        at com.foo.springcontainer.config.persistence.transactionmanager.AtomikosTransactionManagerConfig.atomikosTransactionManager(AtomikosTransactionManagerConfig.java:29)
        at com.foo.springcontainer.config.persistence.transactionmanager.AtomikosTransactionManagerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$beea75cd.CGLIB$atomikosTransactionManager$0()
        at com.foo.springcontainer.config.persistence.transactionmanager.AtomikosTransactionManagerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$beea75cd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$10e69a5.invoke()
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
        at com.foo.springcontainer.config.persistence.transactionmanager.AtomikosTransactionManagerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$beea75cd.atomikosTransactionManager()
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init(): Log already in use?
        ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Log already in use?
        at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.createDefault(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:203)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:258)
```

I have no idea where I'm supposed to go at this point - I might have hoped that whatever file-name it was trying to open would have been included in the logs but I'm flying blind. There is no file created inside /var/log/tomcat7 except the usual catalina and localhost logs.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the application hasn't closed cleanly and it left some residual log locks that then prevent it from starting.

You'll need to find the `tmlogs` folder of your application. Under that, you'll find an `.epoch` file and a `.lck` file. Delete those and your application should start up fine.